# Feasibility for Vulnerability Detection in Smart Contracts

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, bytecode, vulnerability, code

I am excited to find out which is more feasible for vulnerability detection in ethereum smart contracts(solidity): Source Code or ByteCode and what's the reason?

Comment: Can you add more detail? is there a method we should consider when comparing feasibility? or is this from the POV of an auditor?

Comment: From the POV of an auditor, which is more feasible: source or byte code for vulnerability detection in smart contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bytecode is more feasible than Source Code for vulnerability detection due to following reasons:

1. There is an increase in number of programming languages used to develop smart contracts, implementing the best practices to detect can be tiring and hard to enforce across the development tool chain.
2. Automated hardening at the bytecode level bypasses source-level heterogeneity to enforce safety and code integrity properties of contracts independently of the sources from where they were derived.
3. System can enforce policies that protect against integer overflow and underflow vulnerabilities in real Ethereum contract bytecode.

Comment: This is what I have found, if anyone has more or better points, please write them down.

Comment: Well, with source code it is easy to detect certain 'uncommon' patterns. It could be easier to reason about for a human. For automated testing bytecode is easier to deal with.